# Why the one-dimensional wave equation is generated as the current format

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves

The one-dimensional wave equation is $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = v^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$. The higher dimensional wave equation is  $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = v^2 \nabla^2 u $.  What is the reason for not any other format such as $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = (\vec{v} \cdot \nabla)^2 u$?  At least in the latter format the direction of the wave is part of the equation.  Both are solutions for $u(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} + \vec{k} \cdot \vec{v} t)$, in which $\vec{k}$ is the wave vector.